# Passing a function for AlertDialog NegativeButton Listener

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-alertdialog

Would like to pass a function to execute whenever the negative button of an AlertDialog box is displayed. I have a utility function I created to display errors:

```
fun Context.showError(message: String, negativeLabel: Int = R.string.modal_action_dismiss, negativeAction: (() -> Unit)? = null, positiveAction: (() -> Unit)? = null, positiveLabel: Int? = null) {
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    builder.setMessage(message)
    builder.setNegativeButton(negativeLabel) { dialog, _ ->
        dialog.dismiss()
        negativeAction
    }
    // Set positive action only if it exists
    if (positiveAction != null && positiveLabel != null) {
        builder.setPositiveButton(positiveLabel) { dialog, _ ->
            dialog.dismiss()
            positiveAction
        }
    }
    builder.create().show()
}
```

This function worked fine when I call it like so:

```
context?.showError(R.string.modal_action_back) {
    activity?.onBackPressed()
}
```

However, I am using it in a fragment displayed in a `viewPager` and would like the Negative button to trigger moving the page back one page in the viewPager, and the Positive button to trigger moving to the next page in the view pager:

**ViewPagerFragment**

```
class RegistrationPagerFragment : Fragment(), Injectable {

    private val pageOneFragment = PageOneFragment()
    private val pageTwoFragment = PageTwoFragment()
    private val pageThreeFragment = PageThreeFragment()

    ...

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        registrationViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)
                .get(RegistrationViewModel::class.java)

        pageOneFragment.viewPager = this
        pageTwoFragment.viewPager = this
        pageThreeFragment.viewPager = this
    }

    ...

    fun previousPage() {
        if (viewPager.currentItem == 0) return
        var previousPageIndex = viewPager.currentItem - 1
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(previousPageIndex)
    }

    fun nextPage() {
        if (viewPager.currentItem == viewPager.adapter!!.count - 1) return
        var nextPageIndex = viewPager.currentItem + 1
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(nextPageIndex)
    }

    fun onBackPressed() {
        if (viewPager.currentItem > 0) {
            previousPage()
        } else {
            activity?.onBackPressed()
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

**PageOneFragment**

```
class PageOneFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var viewPager: ViewPagerFragment

    ...

    fun someFunctionThatTriggersAlertDialog() {
        context?.showError(
            R.string.some_alert_message,
            negativeLabel = R.string.modal_action_back,
            negativeAction = { 
                viewPager.onBackPressed() 
            },
            positiveLabel = R.string.modal_action_next,
            positiveAction = { 
                viewPager.nextPage() 
            }
         )
    }

    ...
```

When the PageOneFragment's displays that AlertDialog, the negative/positive functions don't call the `viewPager.nextPage()` function.

If I were to put the contents of what's inside of the viewPager.nextPage() function inside of the block I call said function (like I do in the working example above), it would work fine. Why is this?

Answer (score -1):

Why use ViewPager at all? Why don't you handle the fragments from the activity? That way you can always get the previous fragment in the stack or call a function for the next fragment on the positive button.

Comment: I'm asking about a completely different issue, I'm not asking for architecture critiques.